# Maven inside docker container ignoring local repository

Tags: java, docker, maven

I have a maven project with a few custom dependencies that reside on a private repository. I'm attempting to create a docker image based on one of the maven images with these dependencies pre-loaded into the local maven repository.

Dockerfile

```
FROM maven:3.8.6-openjdk-11-slim

COPY settings-docker.xml /usr/share/maven/ref/
COPY bom.xml /tmp

RUN mvn -B -f /tmp/bom.xml -s /usr/share/maven/ref/settings-docker.xml dependency:resolve
```

settings-docker.xml

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <localRepository>/usr/share/maven/ref/repository</localRepository>

    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>Mirror of Private Repo</id>
            <mirrorOf>Private Repo</mirrorOf>
            <name>allows http</name>
            <url>http://here.it.is/repository/</url>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
</settings>
```

bom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Private Repo</id>
            <url>http://here.it.is/repository/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.0.</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I followed the [instructions](https://hub.docker.com/_/maven) from the official maven image on using **/usr/share/maven/ref/repository** for preloaded dependencies. The image builds successfully and when I start it I can see my dependency in both **/usr/share/maven/ref/repository** and in **/root/.m2/repository**.

Despite this when I run maven, it will always attempt to connect to my private repository. Is this some maven behavior I don't know about or is it ignoring my repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have faced with "enhanced local repository manager" feature:

> Enhanced local repository manager is built upon the classical Maven
> 2.0 local repository structure but additionally keeps track of from what repositories a cached artifact was resolved. Resolution of
> locally cached artifacts will be rejected in case the current
> resolution request does not match the known source repositories of an
> artifact, thereby emulating physically separated artifact caches per
> remote repository.

For example:

```
% cat ~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.3.9/_remote.repositories 
#NOTE: This is a Maven Resolver internal implementation file, its format can be changed without prior notice.
#Wed Mar 16 08:49:28 AEDT 2022
spring-core-5.3.9.pom>internal-repository=
spring-core-5.3.9.pom>central=
spring-core-5.3.9.jar>central=
spring-core-5.3.9.jar>internal-repository=
```

You may either disable that feature via specifying `-llr` in maven opts or investigate how force maven to use the same "repository id" in different scenarios.

Comment: This was the problem. It looks like maven now makes a distinction between locally cached artifacts that were originally downloaded from a remote repository and those that were directly installed locally:  https://maven.apache.org/resolver/local-repository.html. So I got around this by using the install:install-file goal